# Python3 SQLite query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am having an issue with a Python3 sqlite query.

This is the following query I ran from the sqlite3 interpreter, it works perfectly:

```
  SELECT {some_columns} FROM {tableA} WHERE bus='ABCD' AND 
    datetime(date_column||" "||time_column) >= datetime('2019-03-19 05:30:00') 
    INTERSECT
  SELECT {some_columns} FROM {tableA} WHERE bus='ABCD' AND
    datetime(date_column||" "||time_column) <= datetime('2019-03-19 05:30:00', '+135 minutes');
```

However when I run the same query in Python as below, it always returns None

```
cur.execute('''SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE bus='ABCD' AND
    datetime(date_column||" "||time_column) >= dateteime(?) 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE bus='ABCD' AND
    datetime(date_column||" "||time_column) <= dateteime(?)''', (
bus,
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
"'%s', '+%s minutes'" % (lookup_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                                              duration)

)).fetchall()
```

Any sort of help or ideas would be appreciated.
The 'bus' and date/time columns have been properly defined in the SQlite tables.

Comment: What does the output look like when you `print` the strings that you're passing in as parameters to your query?

Comment: They all have the values that I expect them to have. I have solved the problem though, using the `datetime` module. Seems there was something wrong with the last part of the code where I was adding minutes to the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT!

I used the datetime module instead. My final python code was:

```
lookup_end_time = lookup_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=135)
```

...code trimmed here...

```
cur.execute('''SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE bus='ABCD' AND
    datetime(date_column||" "||time_column) >= dateteime(?) 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT colA FROM tableA WHERE bus='ABCD' AND
    datetime(date_column||" "||time_column) <= dateteime(?)''', (
bus,
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
lookup_end_time

)).fetchall()
```